# CSS Fonts show as boxes on azurewebsites.net

Tags: html, css, git, cakephp, fonts

I have got a website built in CakePHP and hosted on http://thecontrolist.azurewebsites.net. I am using git to update this website. I am using Coco theme which uses Fontello, Font-Awesome and a few other to create CSS icons in admin panel. When I pushed my work first time, the font's wont show on the live server however they show fine on my localhost/wamp server.

I thought there would have been some kind of file corruption while pushing font files through git. Hence I decided to upload font files in Fontello and Font-awesome using FTP. I hard refreshed and it worked. However, after some time it again stopped working.

I add the entire libs directory of the theme to gitignore list and uploaded all fonts in question using FTP once gitignore had been pushed. But it didn't fix the issue and fonts have stopped showing up again, so the gitignore didn't help.  Any ideas what's going on?

Following the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/coco/libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/coco/libs/fontello/css/fontello.css" />
```

And you can view the files from linked. One thing I am very sure about is that when I reupload files using FTP and refresh it works but then it stops working automatically after some time so it does not seem like a font filepath issue.

Comment: 1. Do you have the fonts 'installed' locally? 
2. Are you hosting the fonts on the same domain?
3. Can you include the code for your font import statement?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use buggy fonts. Use more stable fonts like font-awesome.